# How to redirect to a url with non-English characters?

Tags: python, url, pylons, non-english, webob

I'm using pylons, and some of my urls contains non-English characters, such as:

```
http://localhost:5000/article/111/文章标题
```

At most cases, it won't be a problem, but in my login module, after a user has logging out, I try to get the `referer` from the `request.headers`, and redirect to that url.

```
if user_logout:
    referer = request.headers.get('referer', '/')
    redirect(referer)
```

Unforunately, if the url contains non-English characters, and with a brower of IE, it will report such an error (Firefox is OK):

```
  WebError Traceback:
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 140: ordinal not in range(128) 
View as:   Interactive (full)  |  Text (full)  |  XML (full) clear this 
clear this 
URL: http://localhost:5000/users/logout

Module weberror.evalexception:431 in respond          view
```

There is a way to fix it(but no good), use `urllib.quote()` to convert the url before redirecting.

```
referer = quote_path(url) # only quote the path of the url
redirect(referer)
```

This is not a good solution, because it only works if the brower is IE, and very boring. Is there any good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I still not find a good solution, and use this code:

```
referer = urllib.quote(referer, '.:/?=;-%#')
```

It seems work well now, but I don't feel safe.

Comment: This is the right way of doing it, you should encode every non ASCII character in URL. It's in HTTP specification.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the RFC for non-ascii URLs. They are converted to an ascii equivalent if I remember correctly. You could then redirect to that.

**Edit:** According to @ssokolov (see comments below):

> The specific terms to look up are IDN
>   ([Internationalized Domain Names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)) and
>   [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Comment: This does this conversion:
referer = quote_path(url)

Comment: The specific terms to look up are IDN (Internationalized Domain Names) and Punycode.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect works by raising an exception. This is caught and converted into an HTTP response
How about specifying the charset for your response?

response.charset = 'utf8'

Comment: The bad news is: I have set `response.charset='utf8'`, even `request.charset='utf8'`

Comment: That means the url itself is not getting encoded correctly.
The fix you have provided can be extended.

referer = quote_plus(url.encode('utf8'))

This should enode the non-characters and then quoting the url should work.